# GitHub: Commit a point in history as the head of master

Tags: github

There is a certain commit I did to my Git repository which I host in GitHub. After that commit I've made several other commits, which were bad and redundant, in a second look. I thus need to revert to the certain commit / certain point in history before these bad changes.

I didn't find a button like "revert to this version" or "commit this version as the **head** of this branch (master)".

As you can see, I just want to make that older version the head of the master branch. How will you do that from GitHub?

### Update

I emphasize: I ask on GitHub, not on `git` or any GUI other than GitHub.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: Again, I asked on GitHub. Not on Git. This is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: You should perhaps delete the `git` tag, then; you're likely to get many Git-only answers. I don't believe GitHub *can* do this, though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want a past commit as the last commit on the branch.
If so, using examples with `origin` and `master`:
Use `git reset <comit_id>` and then `git push origin +master` to push & delete all commits past the one you reset to.
 Notice the `+` sign before the branch name (master).
Note that this is irreversible (as far as I know) so take the necessary precautions.

Comment: Sorry for budging in, I didn't know about the + sign myself, is this what deletes the previous commits?

Comment: @Steven Yep. If you reset to a past commit locally and then push with the + sign, all commits in the branch after the one you reset to will be deleted.